# What is the most fast way to run 2 for loop ?

Tags: c#

I have simple code

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < arr.GetLength(0) ; i++)
{
    for( int j = 0 ; j < arr.GetLength(1) ; j++)
    {
         arr[i, j ] = 0;
    }
}
```

I need to make this code to be very fast - so i want to use the `Tasks.Parallel.For`

What will be the most fast and effecint way to use the `Parallel.For` ?

It can be like this

```
Parallel.for( int i = 0 ; i < arr.GetLength(0) ; i++)
{
    Parallel.for( int j = 0 ; j < arr.GetLength(1) ; j++)
    {
         arr[i, j ] = 0;
    }
}
```

or just use one `Parallel.for` ?

Comment: Try both, and _benchmark_ (including against the non-parallel version). Unless the lengths are non-trivial, the parallel version(s) will probably be slower. Oh, and also benchmark inverting both loops (row/column vs column/row).

Comment: One level of parallelism should be enough.  You're probably not going to gain much by parallelizing an already parallel loop, it will in all likelihood do more harm.

Comment: You could also check if the compiler optimizes the `arr.GetLength()` or if it gets called on every loop.

Comment: note: you might want to yank the two dimensions into local variables to avoid `GetLength()` masses of times...

Comment: @Lucas pretty sure that will *not* be optimized; `.Length` is *sometimes* optimized for *vectors*, but not for multi-dim.

Comment: The size of the array can be big  -  but generaly the size is not known .

Comment: @Yanshof all we mean is: is it roughly 10 x 15, or is it 10,000 x 15,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off using the `Parallel.for(...)` on the outer loop only.

The idea being that you would have as many cores in parallel execute the inner loop's iterations.

Comment: Why to use the Parallel.for(...) on the outer loop only ? Can you pls explain whay this wil be better than use it twice ?

Comment: You only have a limited amount of cores.

Comment: Consider the scenario that you have 4 cores that can run threads concurrently. Now you have a loop that iterates over some code. That's fine. Now if inside that code there's a loop that's also trying to be run in parallel then it starts to fall apart a bit. You just have an overdose of loops. Ideally you want (arr.GetLength(0) * arr.GetLength(1)) % Runtime.getRuntime().numberOfAvailableCores() == 0... If you can achieve that you will have the maximum performance.

Answer (score 3):

use this method for both loops:

```
int length0 = arr.GetLength(0);
for( int i = 0 ; i < length0 ; i++)
```

it's faster than every time call the method.

and Parallel.for for the first loop only

Comment: Why to use Parallel.for for the first loop only ?

Comment: creating threads for the inner loop will be slower than just executing the code inside